# OBD2 Mazda 3 Car Doors Codes

Tags: python, obd-ii

I have Mazda 3 (2005).
I read a while ago that i can use ELM327 (OBD2) to do stuff like:

1. Lock & Unlock my cars doors
2. Check whether my car doors are locked
3. Check A/C Temperature ( I don't have the stereo screen anymore )
4. Check A/C Level ( I don't have the stereo screen anymore )

I'm trying to do all those things using Python with Python-OBD.
I read a few articles about manufacturers codes but i can't seem to find a guide on how to do those things.

Comment: This question is a bit off topic as it currently stands;  it is asking for off-site resources; it doesn't present an articulable and tightly scoped problem we can solve.  One way you can make this question on topic is to do a bit more research, and then come to us with an implementation concern you have when you're trying to do something specific with those codes.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Sagi.

Unfortunately your question is not really a programming one and as such it is rather off topic for this site. I suggest hopping over to the sister site https://mechanics.stackexchange.com where auto enthusiasts are reading.

That said, in general, what you can do with OBD2 PIDs is rather limited. I don't know of any vendors which map advanced (and possibly security relevant) features via simple PIDs. You will probably need to dive one level deeper and talk CAN. While you can do this with an ELM327, the exact protocols are vendor specific and really more on topic on the site I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that